# List All Blobs from Azure Storage from a Storage URI?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

Currently, I am working on a storage that is structured as follows:

```
AUTHORS
   > A
      > Adams
      > Agustin
      > Anderson
   > B
      > Boron
      > Brandy
   > C
      > Carson
      > Cruz

...and so on...

   > Z
      > Zeta
      > Zimbabwe
         > Zimbabwe Child Object 1
         > Zimbabwe Child Object 2
```

I was able to write code that will traverse all blobs using the following:

```
var blobClient = new BlobServiceClient("connection-string-to-storage");
var container = blobClient.GetBlobContainerClient("Authors");
var blobsToGet = container.GetBlobs();
```

However, this code will be too expensive because if I would be looking for say "Zimbabwe", I have to get through all the records, down to its child, however deep it may be.

I tried the following but obviously too expensive as well:

```
var blobsToProcess = blobsToGet.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("Zimbabwe"));
```

Alternately, I just used these instead:

```
var cloudContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri("absolute-storage-uri-with-sas"));
var cloudDirectory = cloudContainer.GetDirectoryReference("Authors");
```

I was able to get a collection of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobDirectory object that has a property of "StorageUri.PrimaryUri".

**[Question] How would I get the list of Zimbabwe Child Objects if only I have the primary URI to "Zimbabwe"**

I tried the first code but I am stuck on this:

```
var blobClient = new BlobServiceClient("storageuri-to-zimbabwe");
// I just wanted to get the list of blobs under this storage
var container = blobClient.GetBlobContainerClient(???);
var blobsToGet = container.GetBlobs();
```

Comment: 2 Questions: 1) Name of your blob container is "authors". Correct? and 2) Does your URL looks like `https://account.blob.core.windows.net/authors/Z/Zimbabwe` and you want to fetch all child items beneath that? Correct?

Comment: yes, on both questions.

Answer (score 0):

You may already know this that there are no folders in Azure Blob Storage. It is essentially a 2-level hierarchy - blob container and blobs. The folder you see are virtual and are essentiallu blob prefixes. So in your case, the blob container is `authors` and the blob prefix is `Z/Zimbabwe`.

Considering you get a URL like `https://account.blob.core.windows.net/authors/Z/Zimbabwe`, what you would need to do is parse this to get 2 things: blob container URL and blob prefix. Once you have these two information, you can get the list of blobs that start with the `Z/Zimbabwe` prefix.

Please see the code below. This makes use of `Azure.Storage.Blobs (version 12.8.4)` package:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Storage;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string accountName = "accouny-name";
            string accountKey = "account-key";
            StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
            Uri folderUri = new Uri("https://account.blob.core.windows.net/authors/Z/Zimbabwe");
            string host = folderUri.Host;//"account.blob.core.windows.net"
            //Split local path so that we can extract container name and the folder path i.e. get "authors" and "Z/Zimbabwe";
            var path = folderUri.LocalPath.Split("/", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            //Container name will always be the 1st element in the list.
            string containerName = path[0];//"authors"
            //Remove the first element.
            path.RemoveAt(0);
            //Remaining part is the prefix
            string prefix = $"{string.Join("/", path)}/" ;//"Z/Zimbabwe/"
            //Now get the blob container URI.
            Uri blobContainerUri = new Uri($"{folderUri.Scheme}://{host}/{containerName}");
            BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(blobContainerUri, credential);
            var result = blobContainerClient.GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync(delimiter:"/", prefix: prefix);
            List<string> blobFolders = new List<string>();
            List<BlobItem> blobs = new List<BlobItem>();
            string continuationToken = null;
            do
            {
                await foreach (var blobPages in result.AsPages(continuationToken))
                {
                    continuationToken = blobPages.ContinuationToken;
                    blobFolders.AddRange(blobPages.Values.Where(b => b.IsPrefix).Select(b => b.Prefix));
                    blobs.AddRange(blobPages.Values.Where(b => b.IsBlob).Select(b => b.Blob));
                }
            } while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(continuationToken));
        }
    }
}
```